# Form with picture box not being released

Tags: c#

I am trying to chase a memory leak in a multiform C#.Net application, on Windows 7, VS 2008.

I found this SO post, which indicates that the second form's finalizer should be automatically called
[this.Dispose() doesn't release memory used by Form after closing it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940629/this-dispose-doesnt-release-memory-used-by-form-after-closing-it)
However, it isn't working for me.

Each time a pop up the second form (which contains a large string, and a PictureBox), the amount of memory the app uses increases, even when I force a GC. Interestingly, the String's finalizer IS being called.
I've add a log to both form's Dispose methods; Form2's dispose is being called.

The code is
Form1 (main form)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MemoryLeakTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ~Form1()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "", "Form1.Destructor has been called.\n");
        }

        private void GC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        private void OpenForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form secondForm = null;

            if (secondForm == null)
            {
                secondForm = new Form2();
                secondForm.Show();
            }

            secondForm = null;
        }

        private void UpdateMemory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long memory =  System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            this.MemoryUsage.Text = "Memory usage: " +
                String.Format("{0:n}", memory) +
                " bytes";
        }

        private void AllocateString_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//            StringWrapper wrapper = new StringWrapper();
        }
    }

    public class StringWrapper
    {
        String str = new String('*', 1024 * 1024);

        ~StringWrapper()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "", "StringWrapper finalizer has been called.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

and Form2 is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MemoryLeakTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        StringWrapper wrapper = new StringWrapper();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:/Windows/Web/Wallpaper/Windows/img0.jpg");
        }

        ~Form2()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "", "Form2.Finalizer has been called.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't included the designer generated code, but can add it if need be

Comment: Are you sure you actually have a memory leak (as opposed to memory which has not yet been released by the garbage collector)? Did you try using  `long memory =  System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);` ?

Comment: I'm not convinced enough I'll get a repro to try it.  The code however does show a classic problem in Winforms code.  It uses very little generational memory and does not dispose the bitmap.  Bitmaps are always troublemakers, they use a large amount of unmanaged memory but the Bitmap class object is very small.  PictureBox.Dispose() does *not* also dispose the Image, it cannot assume that it owns the object.  So you have to do it yourself.  Post a screenshot of the memory profiler you use to get more leads.

Comment: Try to declare secondForm as a variable of Form1 and remove the instructions   "secondForm = null;"